# The probability of sample five balls from the urn without replacement

Tags: probability

There's an urn containing 5 red balls, 6 white balls and 7 black balls, then we sample five balls from the urn without replacement. How can I find the probability of each of the following events?

1. The last three balls are all of different colors.
2. Each color appears at least once.

The only way I can figure it out is to list all the possibilities, but it's a huge work I think. Is there any beautiful way to solve this question?

Comment: Surely you must have been taught some bit about the hypergeometric distribution ? Also inclusion-exclusion ?

Comment: *HINT* for part $1:$ Can balls distinguish or have any special preference  for left end or  right end of the line ?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Giving a preliminary hint, that dovetails into the hint of  @trueblueanil : [1] What is the probability that the first ball chosen is red? [2] : What is the probability that the second ball chosen is red? [3] : What is the probability that the third ball chosen is red?  If the answer to these three questions are identical, what is the intuitive explanation for that?